# Cancelling a Jquery hover call when inside a resize script

Tags: jquery, resize, click, hover, window

I have a basic list:

```
<ul class="mainNav">
<li class="menuparent"><a href="#">level one a</a><ul>
    <li><a href="#">level two a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">level two b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">level two c</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">level one b</a></li>
</ul>
```

When the page loads when larger than 600px the following Jquery is used to show and hide the level two navigation via fadeIn/Out:

```
$('li.menuparent').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').fadeIn('slow');
    },function() {
         $(this).children('ul').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

However when the browser window is scaled to be smaller than 600px I use the following Jquery to show/hide the second level nav via toggle:

```
$('li.menuparent').click(function(event) {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});
```

My issue it that even though I have scaled down the window to below 600px because it was loaded  larger than that the hover jquery (fadeIn/Out) is still actioning rather than the toggle.

Do I use stop() and if so what should be my code as I have tried the following but it does not work

```
$('li.menuparent').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop();
});
```

Comment: I would use event delegation and simply add/remove a class from the element so that it matches one delegated event or the other based on window size.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var $lis = $('li.menuparent'),
    flag;
$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (flag != 1 && width < 500) {
        flag = 1;
        $lis.on('click.toggle', function (event) {
            $(this).children('ul').toggle();
        }).off('mouseenter.toggle mouseleave.toggle')
    } else if (flag != 2 && width >= 500) {
        flag = 2;
        $lis.on('mouseenter.toggle', function (event) {
            $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        }).on('mouseleave.toggle', function (event) {
            $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        }).off('click.toggle');
    }
}).resize()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AGV6Y/)

Comment: This works great except if my screen starts smaller than 500px then gets resized to be bigger the mouseenter function is not picked up still you have to click to show the content. Thus it appears to work on resizing of >500 px to <500 but not the other way

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the event handling from the window resize event using event delegation, then control it with adding/removing a class.

```
$(".mainNav").on("click.toggle",".menuparent.clickable",function(){
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
}).on("mouseenter.toggle",".menuparent.hoverable",function(){
    $(this).children('ul').fadeIn('slow');
}).on("mouseleave.toggle",".menuparent.hoverable",function(){
    $(this).children('ul').fadeOut('slow');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 600) {
        $("li.menuparent").removeClass("hoverable").addClass("clickable");
    }
    else {
        $("li.menuparent").addClass("hoverable").removeClass("clickable");
    }
}).resize();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RpA9W/

Comment: This has the same issue as the one by Arun P Johny in that it does not seem to work from <500 to >500 also your jsfiddle is also that off Arun P Johny

Comment: .... <500 to >500 doesn't make sense.... are you saying it only works at 500? i can't make it not work in my fiddle, i reszied it bit by bit from 400-700 without issue. it properly switched from hover to click handling.

Comment: Sorry I meant when the browser starts at less than 500px but gets resized to above 500px. For some reason when I previously testing your jsfiddle it did not work but this time it did, will test further - thanks for your help Kevin B